# Make children of HorizontalScrollView as big as the screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

The way I solved this problem is by creating a custom view for the child views, and then overriding onMeasure() for the custom view. The new onMeasure() sets the width and height to be as large as possible.

The problem is when you show the soft keyboard **and** rotate the phone. With the orientation change and the keyboard showing, onMeasure() sets the "largest" available height to be something ridiculously small, so when I hide the keyboard, the child views have the wrong size.

Is there a way to tell the views to recompute the layout when the keyboard goes away? Or am I doing onMeasure() wrong? Here's the code:

```
@Override 
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){

    int parentWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int parentHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(measureWidth(widthMeasureSpec), 
                         measureHeight(heightMeasureSpec));

    setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
           measureWidth(widthMeasureSpec), measureHeight(heightMeasureSpec))
    );

    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}

public int measureWidth(int measureSpec) {
    int result = 0;
    int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec);
    int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec);
    Display display = ( (WindowManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay(); 
    int screenWidth = display.getWidth();

    if (specMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
        // We were told how big to be
        result = specSize;
    } else {
        // Measure the view
        result = screenWidth;
        if (specMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
            // Respect AT_MOST value if that was what is called for by measureSpec
            result = Math.min(result, specSize);
        }
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Width: "+String.valueOf(result));

    return result;
}
```

measureHeight() is done the same way.

Comment: What do you mean its hard to read? The formatting? What exactly?

Comment: It may be just me but man the multiple lines for "new   LinearLayout    .LayoutParams   " takes up 5 lines when I would probably only use 2 or 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec) uses the passed in values I would think you would want these to be the actual measured width and height:

```
super.onMeasure(measureWidth(widthMeasureSpec), measureHeight(heightMeasureSpec));
```

Comment: Yeah that did it. The child views aren't the right widths now but that's probably because I set the layout dimensions incorrectly.

Comment: @UAvalos After updating what this answer said, the images are bigger than the screen.. Can you tell me how you fixed this? I would really appreciate it!